# Moving project to XCode11 gives NSOrderedCollectionDifference file not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, llvm

I recently moved my Objective-C project to XCode 11

but suddenly i'm getting compile error

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Headers/NSFetchedResultsController.h:44:9: 'Foundation/NSOrderedCollectionDifference.h' file not found
```

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

So i created a new project and compared the old / new project and target settings

turned out i had 
C language dialect set to GNU99 as this was an older project

needed to switch to gnu11

also C++ dialect switched to GNU14